# Valgrind losing symbol info

Tags: dll, debugging, shared-libraries, valgrind

After running Valgrind, the resultant log file contains a number of errors that look like

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
  at 0x3D9863AA: ???
  by 0x3D986287: ???
  by 0x3D9854AC: ???
Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
  at 0x7FCC050: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:214)
  by 0x3D9A56A4: ???
  by 0x3D9A4EB9: ???
```

After looking around I found the following line which I think is important to getting actual content instead of just `???`:

```
Discarding syms at 0x3d97dba0-0x3da53de8 in /path/SomeDLL.so due to munmap()
```

Note that all `???` come from addresses in the ranges specified by `Discarding syms` lines.

What is causing Valgrind to throw away symbol information for shared libraries and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your shared library was unloaded by `dlclose` call. Try to avoid this. See [Valgrind FAQ](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.unhelpful)